# Testing nested namespaced controller with RSpec 2 and Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, controller, rspec

I feel that code will speak more than words in this case, so place to The code :

**config/routes.rb**

```
namespace :embed do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :articles
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/embed/v1/articles_controller.rb**

```
class Embed::V1::ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :text => 'ok'
  end
end
```

**spec/controllers/embed/v1/articles_controller_spec.rb**

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../../spec_helper')

describe Embed::V1::ArticlesController do
  it "should do something" do
    get :new
  end
end
```

**Running `rspec spec`**

```
$ rspec spec
F

Failures:

  1) Embed::V1::ArticlesController should do something
     Failure/Error: get :new
     AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
       The action 'new' could not be found for Embed::V1::ArticlesController
     # ./spec/controllers/embed/v1/articles_controller_spec.rb:5

Finished in 0.01665 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

Any idea why is that? Is there a nested limitation?
Accessing the url **http://0.0.0.0:3000/embed/v1/articles** renders **ok** as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have a the `new` action defined in `Embed::V1::ArticlesController`, only the `index` action. You are trying to hit the `new` action in your specs with `get :new`.

Answer (score 1):

You should define the action new, in your code you didn't defined in controller the new action and called on rspec the new action!